# Ubuntu latest kernel version 6.5.0-14-generic

Tags: kernel, asus, grub-efi, 23.10, logs

I got an error in Ubuntu 23. It shows error -22: `failed to register device with error 22`, then it shows a bunch of logs.

[image: here. sorry for the quality]

I thought if I booted an older kernel version (6.5.0-9) it would work, but I got the same result. I entered recovery mode and updated some packages using apt, but I still got the same result.